# Use Ruby to generate hex codepoints for Unicode values

Tags: ruby, unicode

I'm looking to use Ruby to convert codepoints to values that are easy to look up in Unicode references.

I know that I can get the codepoint itself using `String#codepoints`, (`"a".codepoints => [97]`) but I am looking to output the following via  a few methods, let's call them `convert_unicode`, `convert_unicode_to_hex`, and `convert_unicode_to_codepoints` for the sake of this question:

```
character = "a"
character.codepoints => [97]
convert_unicode("97") => "U+0061"
convert_unicode_to_hex("U+0061") => 0x61
convert_unicode_to_codepoints("U+0061") => 97
```

I tried using `97.to_s(16)` but then got in a mess when I was adding padding of 0's, because another example unicode I'd like this to work for is `U+1F028`. How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-rjust):

```
[97, 127016].map { |i| "U+" << i.to_s(16).upcase.rjust(4, '0') }
#⇒ ["U+0061", "U+1F028"]
```

For other operations:

```
"U+0061"[/(?<=\AU\+).*/].to_i(16)
#⇒ 97
"U+0061"[/(?<=\AU\+).*/].prepend('0x')
#⇒ "0x0061"
```

*NB:* `0x61` might live as string only, since `0x61` and `97` are the same value internally, both represented by `97`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`format`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format):

```
format('U+%04X', 97)     #=> "U+0061"
format('U+%04X', 127016) #=> "U+1F028"
```

- `U+` interpreted literally
- `%` start of format sequence
- `0` pad with zeros
- `4` minimum width of 4 characters
- `X` convert argument to uppercase hex number